# Format string in python odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

How format date in python?

example:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("3.3.2017", '%d.%m.%Y')
    print '{2}-{1}-{0}'.format(dt.day, dt.month, dt.year)
```

console return:  2017-3-3

How get date as:

```
2017-3-3   -- >  2017-03-03   
2017-3-13   -- >  2017-03-13  
2017-10-10   -- >  2017-10-10
```

All date must have a length of 10 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply try with:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("3.3.2017", '%d.%m.%Y')
print '{2}-{1:02d}-{0:02d}'.format(dt.day, dt.month, dt.year)
```

Output:

```
2017-03-03
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dt_test = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(dt_test, type(dt_test))
2017-03-03 <class 'str'>
```